# Access HTTP_REFERER in django Generic Views

Tags: django

I want to pass the previous URL in a context variable for a generic view:

```
class PostDeleteView(DeleteView, LoginRequiredMixin):
      previous_url = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
      ...
```

However, I can't access either `self` or `request`. How do I go about this?

Comment: You can access the request object in any of the class methods. For example `.get_success_url()`

Comment: @bdoubleu can you elaborate? how would I use `.get_success_url()` in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, if you wanted to use the tag `{{ previous_url }}` in your templates you would override the `get_context_data()` method.

Normally you could also pass extra context using the top level attribute `extra_context` but the request object isn't available yet so you will be forced to override.

```
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['previous_url'] = self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
        return context
```

There's a site called [classy class based views](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/) that breaks down all the methods used in Django's built in class based views so you can get an idea of how everything is put together behind the scenes.

Actually I just remembered an easier solution, if you have the request context processor enabled in `TEMPLATES` in your project settings then you can access `{{ request }}` directly in your templates.

```
'context_processors': [
    ...
    'django.template.context_processors.request',
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I don't want to use this as part of the `get_success_url` method? How can I just pass the context to the view?

Comment: Thanks, that seems a long way round. If I can define the variable as `previous_url` in my example I can just call it as `{{ view.previous_url }}`. Is there no other shorter way?

Comment: If you're using class based views the way you pass context to your template is by overriding `get_context_data()`.

Comment: Sure.. but you can't because `self` isn't available until after initializing a class (standard for all python classes) and `self.request` isn't available until after the `.setup()` method is executed. Here's the [official documentation on adding extra context](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context).